# erro ao criar botão de like simples

Tags: php, html, mysql

pessoal tou tentando criar um botão simples de like que simplesmente adiciona +1 em uma tabela na col like, ignorando que pode clicar mais de uma vez e que está sujeito a invasão pois é só um teste. Do jeito que ta agora ele me devolve os seguintes erros:

> Undefined index: tipo in
>   Undefined index: tab in
>   Undefined index: estado in C:\wamp64\www\novo\logado\locais\coleta2.php
>   Undefined variable: varsql in
>   mysqli_query(): Empty query in

A pagina php que faz o like atualizar redireciona pra mesma pagina que está o botao, pordem essa apgina recebe valores de outra pagina, por isso acho que está esses erros, mas tentei já mandar os mesmo dados pelo like.php mas continua dando problema. se alguem puder ajudar com o codigo ou dar uma outra sugestão para fazer um botão que adiciona +1 numa coluna referente a um id especifico.

```
insira o código aqui<?php

        ob_start(); 

      $tipo =$_GET["tipo"];
      $tab = $_GET["tab"];

      include "coleta2.php";
      $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","db_tcc") or die ("Não foi possível se conectar com o servidor.");


        echo "<meta charset='utf-8' />";






        switch($tipo){
            case "0":
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM $tab ORDER BY likes DESC";
                    break;

            case "1": case "2": case "3":
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE TIPO='$tipo' ORDER BY likes DESC";
                    break;
    }





      function Like() { 
   $updd = "";
  $x = 0;
        if ($x == 0) {
          $x = $like + 1;
          $updd = "UPDATE $tab set likes = '$like'+1 where ID = '$id'";

        } else {
          $x = $like - 1;
          $updd = "UPDATE $tab set likes = '$like'-1 where ID = '$id'";

        }
        mysqli_query($conexao, $updd);
       }







       $carregar_guias = mysqli_query($conexao, $varsql);

echo "<div class='loc'>";

      while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($carregar_guias))
      {
        $id = $linha["id"];
        $blob = $linha["foto"];
        $nome = $linha["nome"];
        $desc = $linha["descricao"];
        $like = $linha["likes"];

       $img = imagecreatefromstring($blob); 

        ob_start(); 
        imagejpeg($img, null, 80);
        $data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();




        echo "<table class='tablel'><tr>";
        echo "<td>".  htmlentities(utf8_encode($nome), 0, "UTF-8")."</td>";  
        echo "<td> <form name='like' method='get' action='like.php?            tab=$tab&id=$id'><INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Curtir' ></form></td>
        <td>$like </td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='3' class='imag'>";

          echo '<img  src="data:image/jpg;base64,' .  base64_encode($data)  . '" class="imag"  />';

        echo "</td></tr>
        <tr><td class='desc' colspan='3'  >".  htmlentities(utf8_encode($desc), 0, "UTF-8")."</td></tr>
        </table><br>";



      }
      echo "</div>";
    ?>
```

pag like.php

```
<?php

$id =$_GET["id"];
      $tab = $_GET["tab"];
      $tipo = $_GET["tipo"];

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_tcc") or die ("Não foi possível se conectar com o servidor.");
$updl = "UPDATE $tab set likes = likes +1 where id = '$id'";
mysqli_query($conexao, $updl);

header('location:din.php');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tente remover as seguintes linhas da função like:**

```
 $x = $like + 1;

$x = $like - 1;
```

***e colocar isso:***

```
 if($x == 0){
      $updd = "UPDATE $tab set likes = likes + 1 where ID = '$id'";

    } else {
      $updd = "UPDATE $tab set likes = likes - 1 where ID = '$id'";

    }
    mysqli_query($conexao, $updd);
```